# If Condition Simplification

Tags: c#, algorithm, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I'm refactoring a code snippet in which I see the following condition that I wonder whether it's simplified.

```
data.RecordId != 0 || (data.RecordId == 0 && data.SerialNum == "0000")
```

Isn't `data.RecordId == 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000"` same of that?

If it is possible, how come? Could you detailed?

Comment: `if (data.RecordId != 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000")` for short. Either `data.RecordId != 0` or (if `data.RecordId == 0`) `data.SerialNum == "0000"`

Comment: I see another runtime difference that deals with the shortcut evaluation of `&&`: if `data.RecordId == 0` is false in the longer expression, it will not evaluate the right part will SerialNum, which can avoid sth. like a null ref.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko why did you remove your answer, sir? I think to examine it ?

Comment: @concurrencyboy as mention by Stgefano in the comments of my answer, there is an typo in your Q, as you asked: "Isn't data.RecordId == 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000" same of that?" this is not correct it's `data.RecordId != 0 `  If this is a typo ok, if not that may be your solution.

Answer (score 5):

yes, it's possible, assuming you had a typo (!= not ==)...

let Wolfram Alpha explain:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%3A+R+%21%3D+0+%7C%7C+%28R+%3D%3D+0+%26%26+S%3D%3D+0000%29

R!=0 ∨ (R = 0 ∧ S = 0)

is simplyfied as:

R!=0 ∨ S = 0

the explaination step by step:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws
Distributivity of ∨ over ∧ says:

```
x v (y ∧ z) = (x ∨ y) ∧ (x ∨ z)
```

in you case:

```
R! ∨ (R ∧ S) = (R! ∨ R) ∧ (R! ∨ S)
```

where `(R! ∨ R)` is always true and you can ommit it as the 1st operand in the and logic:

```
R! ∨ (R ∧ S) = true ∧ (R! ∨ S)

R! ∨ (R ∧ S) =  (R! ∨ S)
```

voilá

But I see another kind of runtime difference that deals with the shortcut evaluation of `&&`:

if data.RecordId == 0 is false in the longer expression, it will not evaluate the right part with data.SerialNum, which can avoid getting a null ref.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander well actually he has wrote `R== 0`  not `R!= 0` unless is a typo (and I think so ) the answer is: No this isn't the same, or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You could just say:

```
data.RecordId != 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000"
```

The `data.RecordId == 0` check is unnecessary, we've already determined that `data.RecordId != 0` doesn't hold, so it follows that `data.RecordId == 0` is true. Remember that boolean conditions are evaluated from left to right, and they short-circuit: in the case of an `||`, evaluation stops if the first condition is true.

Another way to look at it is by using boolean logic, symbolically your expression can be represented and simplified as follows:

```
1. ¬p ∨ (p ∧ q)
2. (¬p ∨ p) ∧ (¬p ∨ q)
3. true ∧ (¬p ∨ q)
4. ¬p ∨ q
```

- `p` represents the condition `data.RecordId == 0`
- `q` represents the condition `data.SerialNum == "0000"`
- In line 1 we apply the distributive property
- In line 2 we apply the identity that states that `¬p ∨ p` is always `true`
- In line 3 we apply the identity that says that `true ∧ p` is `p`
- And that's how we arrive at the simplification of line 4

Comment: How do you think its calculation? Would you mind explaining it which I actually wonder

Comment: @concurrencyboy I did a better job now, explaining the simplification in terms of boolean logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.RecordId != 0)
```

then

```
(data.RecordId == 0)
```

will be true. so no need to mention that just

```
data.RecordId != 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000"
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for

```
data.RecordId != 0 || (data.RecordId == 0 && data.SerialNum == "0000")
```

- If `data.RecordId != 0` we return `true`.
- If `data.RecordId != 0` fails, the **only** option is `data.RecordId == 0` and thus check for it is *redundant*

So we can *drop* `data.RecordId == 0`:

```
data.RecordId != 0 || (data.SerialNum == "0000")
```

Or

```
data.RecordId != 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be

```
data.RecordId != 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000"
```

But, from your condition 1, `data.SerialNum == "0000"` should be validated only when `data.RecordId == 0` is true. What if `data.RecordId` is other than 0.

So, this one is correct for the above case

```
data.RecordId != 0 || (data.RecordId == 0 && data.SerialNum == "0000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple explanation is like:

When we got
**data.RecordId != 0 || (data.RecordId==0 ...)** 
the first part (**data.RecordId != 0**) says anything except 0 means **true**. if it is not, then we will go for second part (**data.RecordId==0**) and definitely when we are here, value of data.RecordId would be 0 and means **always true**. (because we check everything except 0 in first part of condition).
So then the only valuable part of second condition is **data.SerialNum == "0000**
and the we would have

```
data.RecordId != 0 || data.SerialNum == "0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

No it would not necessarily by the same as ==0 is checking for int value and "0000" is checking for string value